# Instant run - Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, performance-testing, android-instant-run

Google announced instant run a year ago, and until this time I can't use it.

I tried more than 10,000 times for many android studio versions,
it works for the first run but the second, it always build failed because it can't delete some files or whatever.

And every time I have to clean the project then run again, which means there is no added value to turn on the instant run.

What is the problem? what's going on with google? They just announce the features without any test. Come on guys.

Any advice guys?

Error:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Could not delete path '/**/**/**/**/app/build/intermediates/instant-run-support/**/debug/package_directories/dex-renamer-state.txt'.`

Comment: Please provide more details about exception you have got on failed build.

Comment: Works pretty well for me. Which files are you editing? Which Android studio version are you using?

Comment: "They just announce the features without any test" - just as usual. Honestly instant run worked for me, but sometimes when you need to rebuild project to apply changes which can't be applied though instant run - the rebuilding process takes too long, so I turned instant run off.

Comment: I have added the error

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you are in unix system 
`chmod 777 <ProjectPath>/app/build/intermediates/instant-run-support/debug/package_directories/dex-renamer-state.txt`

Comment: I'm using mac, but i will try to find a way in use something like that in mac

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, No More instance run :(